# Getting response from database as array instead of seperate objects

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, express

I want to get the response from a database callback function as an array, instead of seperate objects. The problem is that with the current setup Express throws an 'Headers already set' error.

I think the problem lays within the database callback function:

File: database_connection.js

```
exports.connection = {
query: function () {
    var queryArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
        events = [],
        eventNameIndex = {};

    pool.getConnection(function (err, conn) {
        if (err) {
            if (eventNameIndex.error) {
                eventNameIndex.error();
            }
        }
        if (conn) {
            var q = conn.query.apply(conn, queryArgs);
            q.on('end', function () {
                conn.release();
            });
            console.log(events);
            events.forEach(function (args) {
                q.on.apply(q, args);
            });
        }
    });

    return {
        on: function (eventName, callback) {
            events.push(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
            eventNameIndex[eventName] = callback;
            return this;
        }
    };
}};
```

I use it like this:

File: database_operations.js

```
exports.streepjes = function(){
  return {
    getByUserID: function(userid, callback_streepjes){
      sqlSelect = sqlQuery.select();
      //QUERY:
      let command = sqlSelect.from('steepjes').select('*').where({USERID: userid}).build();
      database.connection.query(command).on('result', function(result){
        console.log("ANOTHER ONE");
        console.log(result);
        return callback_streepjes(result);
      }).on('error', function(err){
        console.error(err);
      });
    }
  }
};
```

And I use these functions in an express router function:

```
router.get('/getStrepenByUserID', function(req, res) {
  database_operations.streepjes().getByUserID(req.query.userid, function(response){
    res.json(response);
  });
});
```

The problem with this approach is that the callback function in the route gets called multiple times. This creates the header already set error.

**Definite question:**

I want to change the database connection function in such a way that it returns all of it's output in one string, instead of calling the callback function on every database entry. But I just cannot figure out how to do this. Maybe someone can give a hint on how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

I use MySQL and the functions do work correctly when you only get one item, it crashes when it responds with multiple rowdatapackets

**Provisional answer:**

See my answer

Comment: MySQL, added it to the question aswell

Answer (score 0):

Made it work by changing the function in database_operations to this:

```js
exports.streepjes = function(){
  return {
    getByUserID: function(userid, callback_streepjes){
      sqlSelect = sqlQuery.select();
      //QUERY:
      let command = sqlSelect.from('steepjes').select('*').where({USERID: userid}).build();
      let output = [];
      database.connection.query(command).on('result', function(result){
        output.push(result);
      }).on('error', function(err){
        console.error(err);
      }).on('end', function(){
        return callback_streepjes(output);
      });
    }
  }
};
```

Basically pushing every element on an array called output, and then returning it only after the 'end' event has fired. If there is a better way to fix it, please let me know!